# DB2 SQL Count over Union of multiple tables with different Datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, cobol

I want to union multiple tables and some of them want to count.

```
Select A.CustomerId
      , A.CustomerGroup
      , ‘’        as count
From Customer A
Union 
Select  B.CustomerId
      , B.CustomerGroup
      , select(count(*) from Product C
                   Where C.productId = B.productId) as count
From Product B
```

The problem occurred that column 3, of the operands of a set operator are not compatible.

Comment: Please show minimal sample data and the expected results set.

Comment: is cobol still living ? :)

Comment: Yes in large scale.

Comment: @Jen . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

try like below,  for union you need same datatype

```
Select A.CustomerId
      , A.CustomerGroup
      , 0   as count
From Customer A
Union 
Select  B.CustomerId
      , B.CustomerGroup
      , select(count(*) from Product C
                   Where C.productId = B.productId
      ) as count
From Product B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend the third column of the union to be numeric (e.g. an integer), then *all* queries contributing to the union would need to have that type.  In addition, you should probably rewrite the second query to use a left join rather than a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    A.CustomerId,
    A.CustomerGroup
    0 AS count
FROM Customer A
UNION ALL
SELECT
    B.CustomerId,
    B.CustomerGroup,
    COUNT(C.productid)
FROM Product B
LEFT JOIN Product C
    ON C.productId = B.productId
GROUP BY
    B.CustomerId,
    B.CustomerGroup;
```

Note: I am assuming that you really want `UNION ALL` here.  If instead your logic is that a given customer ID and group can really only belong to either the `Customer` or `Product` table, then continue using `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Since from your query it seems like you need blank space for your `column 3`.

```
Select A.CustomerId
      , A.CustomerGroup
      , Cast(NULL as INT)  as count
From Customer A
Union All
Select DISTINCT B.CustomerId
      , B.CustomerGroup
      , count(*) as count
From Product B INNER JOIN 
Product C Where C.productId = B.productId
```

Comment: This is the not the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this returns exactly the result that you have, but it seems more useful:

```
SELECT C.CustomerId, C.CustomerGroup,
       COUNT(p.productid)
FROM Customer C LEFT JOIN
     Product P
     ON C.CustomerId = P.CustomerId AND
        C.CustomerGroup = P.CustomerGroup
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.CustomerGroup;
```

I am suspicious that both `Customer` and `Product` have the columns `CustomerId` and `CustomerGroup`.

I suspect that your original query might be wrong and you might really intend:

```
SELECT C.CustomerId, C.CustomerGroup,
       COUNT(p.productid)
FROM Customer C LEFT JOIN
     Product P
     ON C.ProductId = P.ProductId 
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.CustomerGroup;
```